# What’s the difference between these two sentences? It’s about “,”

Tags: grammar

1. He has two sons who are doctors,
2. He has two sons, who are doctors

My professor taught us about that “,”
She said that the location of “,” changes the meaning of sentence.
What’s the difference between those sentences?

Comment: Don't think of it as a piece of written text. Think of it as *spoken* - with no pauses at all in the first one, but a significant pause after ***sons*** in the second. That's how native speakers learn to distinguish the two meanings, long before they know what a comma is.

Answer (score 3):

#1 means he may have other sons. The relative clause is a defining one.  Another sentence may follow:

> He has two **other** sons who are engineers.

#2 means he has no other sons.  The relative clause is a non-defining one, and we can delete it without significantly changing the meaning of the sentence:

> He has two sons.

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped a lot <3

Answer (score 2):

They can be paraphrased thus:
1’. Two of his sons are doctors.
2’. He has two sons, and both of them are doctors.

Comment: Thank you so much!